Wagtail AWS CloudFront Cache Invalidation
Hi Following the docs here
https://docs.wagtail.org/en/v6.2/reference/contrib/frontendcache.html#amazon-cloudfront
for Wagtail and AWS CloudFront
it states config for AWS CF is
WAGTAILFRONTENDCACHE = {
    'cloudfront': {
        'BACKEND': 'wagtail.contrib.frontend_cache.backends.CloudfrontBackend',
        'DISTRIBUTION_ID': 'your-distribution-id',
        'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID': os.environ['FRONTEND_CACHE_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
        'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY': os.environ['FRONTEND_CACHE_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
        'AWS_SESSION_TOKEN': os.environ['FRONTEND_CACHE_AWS_SESSION_TOKEN']
    },
}

However it implies that AWS_SESSION_TOKEN is an environment settings?
But isnt AWS_SESSION_TOKEN generated at run time using the KEY and SECRET KEY and
this the config is in the Django settings file
Does not seem to make sense
